# Trying to find a function

Tags: polynomials, substitution

Hello I was looking at where x^n and xn intersect as I was changing n and I realized they made a exponential type pattern so I tried for about 2 weeks to find this function but was not able to do so. I was wondering if this function can’t be normally graphed and if so then can you use it to make other inter sectioning functions of which there intersecting function makes a function that can’t normally be represented here is the problem I was looking at https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8qh8lsmvpj

Comment: Do you mean you want to solve $x^n = x n$ for $x$? Or for $n$?  The former is quite routine, the second requires the Lambert W function.

Comment: @RobertIsrael If you take a look at the graph I showed you, you can see the I plotted 2 points an exponential function and it’s inverse I want the function that lines up with those points

Comment: @RobertIsrael To clarify a bit more I want to solve for n I have already solved for x as that’s the x_1 part on the graph

Comment: Search for "x^n=xn solve n" on Wolframalpha.com. You can find informations about $W_{c_1}$ with this link: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html .